# merge string to variable without line break?

Tags: php

I have a problem but i don't know how to fix it 
I have code like this :

```
$link= 'http://www.example.com/2ne1-albums-list';
for($k=1 ;$k<= 4 ;$k++)
{
   $new_link =  $link.'-'.$k.'.html';
   echo $new_link."\r\n" ;                                                             
 }
```

I tried echo in CMD and result like this

```
http://www.example.com/2ne1-albums-list
-1.html
http://www.example.com/2ne1-albums-list
-2.html
```

But i want it like this :

```
http://www.example.com/2ne1-albums-list-1.html
http://www.example.com/2ne1-albums-list-2.html
```

Tried to used trim() but it not work ?

Edit: Finally solved the problem . I tried to used trim() in $link . And It worked normally :) .Thanks Vincent Beltman for the idea :D

Comment: Are you sure this isn't working?  Looks like it should produce exactly the strings you're looking for.

Comment: yes. it's not work . The important is i run it in cmd . May be it not work ?

Comment: if it did not work i am deleting it sorry

Comment: it should work in browser don't know about cmd

Comment: Running the exact same code (copy/pasted) works fine on my machine (from command line too). Weird PHP configuration?

Comment: I'm pretty sure this will work in the script, don't know why it's not displaying correctly when run from the command line.

Comment: I used xampp and I never configuration anything :))

Comment: sorry for the wrong answer, but i just check as well like others, it work fine

Answer (score 0):

Just a guess maybe its because of the cmd. If the line gets too long, it will be printed on the next line. Like this:

```
http://www.example.com/2ne1-albums-list # <-Max characters for cmd.
-1.html # Cmd prints on next line
```

Comment: can you explain how to config it ?